# An e-commerce framework to use in conjunction with symfony2?

Tags: symfony, e-commerce

I have a requirement for a site that is about 70% blog and articles, 30% e-commerce. I want to do the site using symfony2, and was wondering if any e-commerce frameworks work well with it?

I've seen some information on sylius, which seems early on, and sonata, likewise. I know that Magento would be an established choice (as long as I don't need to customize it much!), but don't know about having the two live together without appearing to be separate sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Thelia2](http://thelia.net/v2) is another symfony2 based ecommerce solution. This project is currently in beta version and is due to be released at the end of 2013.

The beta version of Thelia 2 is hosted on Github and can be downloaded on the dedicated Thelia 2 website: [thelia.net/v2](http://thelia.net/v2)

Answer (score 0):

There's [vespolina](https://github.com/vespolina/vespolina), the symfony2 ecommerce initiative, which looks promising but it's still in its early stages. Drupal version 8, a popular CMS is moving towards symfony2 and they may have some ecommerce plugins. That might be your best fit based on your ratios.